# On SWT button, how to position text in front of image

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a button and i'm trying to set text and image on it by :

```
button.setText("+");
button.setImage( PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage( ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FILE ) );
```

But, this pice of code makes the image to appear before text.

I want it the other way i.e. text before the image.

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add a `PaintListener` to your button and do the hard work on its `paintControl` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`, but I'm not sure if this works on all platforms.

```
Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Comment: This option is intended for right-to-left writing systems, such as Arabic or Hebrew. ``SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`` should not be used in left-to-right environments, simply to change the image's position on the button (though it will). This feature will very likely cause other problems, e.g. with the text on the button.